# Cannot assign value to specific textView in RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm new to android dev and I wanted to make app with fragments and use RecyclerView inside it. I'm getting error which is saying that I'm trying to use setText on a null object.
My code looks like that :

```
public static class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private static String[] newsTitle = new String[] {...};
        private static String[] newsDescs = new String[] {...};

        public ContentAdapter(ViewGroup parent) {}

        @Override
        public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView titles;
            TextView descs;
            public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
                super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false));
                titles = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.list_title);
                descs = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.list_desc);
            }
        }

         @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
             return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
         }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.titles.setText(newsTitle[position]); //Here is error
            holder.descs.setText(newsDescs[position]); 
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() { return newsTitle.length; }
    }
```

Comment: From a quick look at your code I think that replacing `parent` with `itemView` in your `ViewHolder` might solve the issue.

Comment: changed parent to itemView but nothing changed, still the same error

Comment: Have you checked whether the `item_list` layout actually contains a `TextView` with the `android:id="@+id/list_title"` set? I'm aware that this is a common mistake, so I'm just asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a correct example if a view holder

```
public static class HeaderVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView textView;

    public HeaderVH(View view){
        super(view);
        textView = (TextView)view;
    }

}
```

You need to pass in a the View object of the row to the viewholder, not the parent View object. This is an example of onCreateViewHolder()

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_setting_header, parent, false);
      RecyclerView.ViewHolder  vh = new HeaderVH(v);
return vh;
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-1-fundamentals-for-listview-experts/